# ngRepeat in custom directive - interpolation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Working on creating a custom directive to populate a drop-down menu, but am facing problems when trying to set the `ng-repeat` attribute of the `<li>` in my directive.

I am expecting this to create a drop down option for each environment of my tool, using `ng-repeat`.

I am not getting any errors in the console, but the `$scope` variable is not being interpolated as expected.

**Here is my directive:**

```
myApp.directive("toolsMenu", function () {
   return {
       replace: true,
       transclude: true,
       templateUrl: 'js/directives/toolsMenu.html',
       scope: {
           inputObject: '=',
           environment: '=',
           tool: '@'
       }
   } 
});
```

**Here is the** `toolsMenu.html`  **file:**

```
<li class="tool">{{inputObject.name}}
    <ul class="environment">
       <li ng-repeat="environment in {{tool}}"><a ng-href="{{ environment.url }}" alt="{{inputObject.name}} {{ environment.environment }}" target="_blank">{{ environment.environment }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**This is how I call my directive form the main HTML file:**

```
<tools-menu input-object="continuusInput" environment="continuus" tool="continuus"></tools-menu>
```

**This is the console output open running the page:**
[image]

In this example, the "tool" is actually supposed to be 'continuus', but it is only appearing as 'tool'.

Comment: Why would you want it to be `environment in continuus`? There is no variable `continuus` in your directive's scope. `{{tool}}` wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: Because continuus is the value of tool in this insurance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<li ng-repeat="environment in tool"><a ng-href="environment.url" alt="{{inputObject.name + environment.environment}}" target="_blank">{{ environment.environment }}</a></li>
```

You don't need to add brackets ({{}}) when defining attributes on html

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :( It looks like the directive isn't even finding my $scope variables for some reason. I'm not sure why.